# list permission data from tfs 2013

Tags: java, tfs, sdk

i need to list project-collection level's permission and project level's permission on my project. now i have connected to tfs and i have got project collection list and user list via tfs java sdk. but i can't find the way to get the permission name list and permission list.

i have checked the database, and find that the actions have some discrepancies with the tbl_securityaction'data.

**my code**

```
TFSConfigurationServer configurationServer = SnippetSettings.connectToTFS().getConfigurationServer();

    GUID[] resourceTypes = new GUID[] { CatalogResourceTypes.PROJECT_COLLECTION };

    CatalogResource[] resources = configurationServer.getCatalogService().queryResourcesByType(resourceTypes, CatalogQueryOptions.NONE);

    if (resources != null) {
        for (CatalogResource resource : resources) {
            String instanceId = resource.getProperties().get("InstanceId");
            TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = configurationServer.getTeamProjectCollection(new GUID(instanceId));
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me some advice on that?